# jquery autocomplete - prevent closing it when clicking on outside div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

So - jquery autocomplete and extra div with special character icons that can be inserted into a search box (such as É, ã etc)...

Whenever user types - autocomplete dropdown show up, but when user needs to click on a special character icon (so it would be inserted into a searchbox) -> autocomplete dropdown predictably closes as focus has been lost:(

Is there a way to prevent jquery autocomplete dropdown from hiding on lost focus in cases when user clicks on one of the special character icons?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: This is directed towards the jquery autocomplete combobox for use with selectbox, but the same solution and thought process definitely applies for autocomplete as well (I was working on the combobox when I came across your problem :)

**HTML:**

```
<select class="combobox">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="add_another">Add Another Option</option>
</select>
```

**CSS:**

```
.force-open{
    display:block !important;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
$( ".combobox" ).combobox({

     // the select event is apparently the only event
     // that you can pass a function, so if your goal
     // is to keep it open specifically when a user
     // clicks an option, then this is where you should start

     select: function(event, ui) {
            $(event.currentTarget)
            .parent()
            .next("ul")
            .addClass("force-open");
     }
});


$(".custom-combobox .ui-button").click(function(){

    //This is the actual answer to your question,
    //which is specifically forcing the jquery selectbox
    //to stay open after it has already been opened,
    //regardless of the change in focus.

    $(this)
    .parent()
    .next("ul")
    .addClass("force-open");
})
});
```

**Explanation:**

Normally what I try to do if there are no good exposed events for a given library or chunk of code when doing web development (other than try to hack at/update the source code...) is look at the structure of html that is generated from the library/js (if there is any at all).

In this case, the generated html from jquery-ui after calling $( ".combobox" ).combobox({...}) is:

```
<select class="combobox" style="display: none;">
....shown above in HTML section...
<span class="custom-combobox">
<span class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible" role="status" aria-live="polite">4 results are available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate.</span>
<input class="custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left ui-autocomplete-input" title="" autocomplete="off">
<a class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-icon-only custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" tabindex="-1" title="Show All Items" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
</span>
<ul id="ui-id-1" class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" tabindex="0" style="display: none; width: 209px; top: 43px; left: 8px;">
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
<a id="ui-id-2" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Volvo</a>
</li>
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
<a id="ui-id-3" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Saab</a>
</li>
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
<a id="ui-id-4" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Mercedes</a>
</li>
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
<a id="ui-id-5" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Add Another Option</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

This gives me a great jumping-off point in order to add/remove css classes in order to force the functionality I want. Remember, this is a **last resort**, and should only be abused when there isn't a fully featured api to help bind/unbind events. By examining the html structure, I can use jquery selectors/methods to get at the correct 'ul' tag I am trying to keep open, in this case. So after I grab the ul I want using jquery, I addClass 'force-open' which has 'display:block !important;' , ultimately forcing the jquery combobox to stay open, regardless of focus. Now simply removeClass 'force-open' when you feel it is time to 'shut' the combobox.

Hope this helps :).